# Java Web Service - Accepting XML Input

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee

I'm having an issue with a Java Web Service in that I can't accept XML Input from a form (developed by another group).

Not having worked with services like this before I am unsure whether I have setup it up correctly, currently all I want it to do is connect, so methods are empty.

```
package com.what.service;

import java.io.File;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.swing.text.*;



@WebService

public class HouseGetForm {

    @WebMethod
    public String getRooms(String rooms) { 
        return "Number of Rooms: " + rooms;
    }

    @WebMethod
    public String getHouseType(String house) {
        return "House Type " + house;
    }

    @WebMethod
    public String getKitchenAppliances(String appliance) {
        return "Appliances " + appliance;
    }
```

I also have my "Server" class, which was nabbed almost directly from a tutorial.

```
package com.what.service;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;


public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:9898/HouseGetForm", new HouseGetForm());

        System.out.println("House Get form Initailised.");

        System.out.println("Server Started...");


    }

}
```

You see, I'm not really sure how the whole process works so I'm stumbling around in the dark a bit. When the form is submitted, How is the XML delivered? As a whole document which I then have to find the individual field values on the Web Service? If so how is this done?

I literally need to know in laymans terms how I can take XML input (Which is the form data) in a Java Web Service and then manipulate it in Java Web Service Methods.

Comment: unable to co-relate your question and the WS code that you have shared.The form data cannot be bound with the WS implicitly, the WS operations needs to be invoked somewhere. You may be able to perform marshelling from XML to Java objects using JAXB and then maipulate to form the request for the webservice

Comment: I do also have my server class, probably should of included that.
Edited the Q and added now.

Answer (score 3):

> Not having worked with services like this before I am unsure whether I
>   have setup it up correctly, currently all I want it to do is connect,
>   so methods are empty.

I recommend you to go through a REST jersey library tutorials for this. Please read this article [REST](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html)

---

So basically what happens is that your form submits a XML file over HTTP instead of HTML file.
If you want to receive XML data over webservice client (REST).
You have to declare a method that

> Consumes

XML data. For example

```
@WebMethod
@Consumes("application/xml")
@Produces("application/xml")
public String test(String xmlData){
  System.out.println(xmlData); //reads xml data
  returns "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><note>Hello!</note>"; //this will display the legit XML file on to browser instead of HTML document
}
```

[Example of the legit xml file displayed on browser](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml)

Morever, you can use the powerful library called **JAXB** to take this xmlData and convert into a JavaBean object straight away. Also let me show you what is happening in overall (I guess this is what you are asking)

Here is a WebMethod. This is something your client is going to invoke if they want to use your webservice.

```
@WebMethod
@Consumes("application/xml")
@Produces("application/xml")
public String test(Person person){
  System.out.println(person.getFirstName()); //reads xml data
  returns "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><note>Hello!</note>"; //this will display the legit XML file on to browser instead of HTML document
}
```

Here is an example of XML data for person sent from client

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Person>
   <firstName>Temp</firstName>
   <lastName>Nick</lastName>
</Person>
```

When this file reaches the method test(Person person); using JAXB, this XML data converts into Person object below

```
  @XmlRootElement
    public class Person {
      private String firstName;
      private String lastName;

      public String getFirstName(){
        return fristName;
      }
      @XmlElement
      public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
         this.firstName = firstName;
      }

     //another getter and setter for lastName

  }
```

Comment: This @Consume annotation, what's it part of? I don't seem to be able import it from Default Libraries? - Just found it. REST

Answer (score 0):

Form data is delivered as encoded HTTP.

I'm betting that your XML is coming over via an HTTP POST.  You can find out by starting your app, opening the page in a browser like Chrome, and turning on Wireshark to see what is being sent on the wire.

Once you know that, you'll realize that you have to extract the XML from the HTTP request and serialize it to Java objects.  Some people like JAXB to do such things.